# NLP: What is the appropriate way to use engineered features in a sklearn pipeline?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm conducting a text classification task for my first time (twitter sentiment analysis), but I'm unsure of how to incorporate engineered features into my sklearn pipeline.

So far I have tried transformations before outputting a classifier. For example:

```
model = Pipeline([('t', 'mean_vectorizer'), ('logreg', LogisticRegression())])
```

but all of these basic pipelines yield very low scores. So I want to start conducting grid searches and incorporating my own features.

So far, my data set (X_train) is such that the rows are tweets (single string). This is the format handled by mean_vectorizer (and tfidf_vectorizer if I use it).

**Incorporating new features**

Take for example 1 new feature, a boolean value for whether or not a positive word exists (just a basic example). I would create a (len(X_train), 1)-dimensional array of boolean values corresponding to each tweet.

My ideas:

1. After preprocessing the tweets, tokenize them and replace the words with values from a word2index dict. Pad the tweets to equal length, and then concatenate this array with my features. Then pass this into the Pipeline as normal.
2. Maybe there is a way in which these features can be passed individually into the Pipeline?
3. Maybe the transformations will have issues using an array of integers instead of strings?

**Question**

Could someone please advise on the best way to go forward with this using sklearn.

Assume that the data is a list of sentences (training separate from testing) and each sentence is a single string.

I think this will be a really helpful for other people starting out with NLP, so please be as general as possible.

Comment: Combine your new feature with the features found from the vectorizer by using [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html). See [this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html)

Comment: @VivekKumar Thanks for the comment. If you have any experience doing this and some spare time, it would be great if you could create an answer. Thanks again for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incorporating features into a pipeline can be done using sklearn's `FeatureUnion`, as suggested by Vivek Kumar with details found here on the scikit-learn website: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html.

When using the Pipeline, it should be split into a number of sections sections, with 3 important ones: the extraction of data, then the `FeatureUnion`, and then a classifier. Within the `FeatureUnion`, there will likely be multiple pipelines corresponding to different features, such as a bag of words model, Tfidf, ad-hoc features, etc.

As can be seen in detail in the link provided above, the pseudo-structure is like so:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([

    # Get array of text
    ('text', TextExtractor()),

    # Use FeatureUnion to combine the features used in classification
    ('union', FeatureUnion(
        transformer_list=[

            ('text2', Pipeline([('f', feature1)])),

            ('body_bow', Pipeline([('tfidf', some_vectorizer)])),

            # Pipeline for pulling ad hoc features from text
            ('body_stats', Pipeline([('f2', feature_dictionary)]))])),

    # Use a SVC classifier on the combined features
    ('clf', classifier()),
])
```